# Passing a std::function to a class constructor in c++11, more specifically initialising the corresponding member correctly

Tags: c++, vtable

I am trying to pass a function to the constructor of my class but I don't get how to correctly initialize the corresponding member.

I am relatively new to C++ and would be very thankful for your help.

```
class Derivative {
  public:
    Derivative(const std::function<double(double, std::vector<double>)>f,
               std::vector<double> pars,
               ) : _f(f), _pars(pars) {};
    virtual ~Derivative();

    double exampleUse(double x) const {
      return (_f(x, pars) - _f(x + 1, pars)) / 2.;
    }

  private:
    const std::function<double(double, std::vector<double>)> _f;
    std::vector<double> _pars;
};
```

which results in:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for Fitter::Derivative", referenced from:
      Fitter::Derivative::Derivative(std::__1::function<double (double, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >)>, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >) in firstModelFit.cc.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Where are you constructing the object?

Comment: Add a definition for your destructor. `virtual ~Derivative(){}`. And remove the `const` from the first parameter in your constructor, so that you can apply a `std::move` in your initializer list

Comment: I think your destructor is missing a definition. try: `virtual ~Derivative(){}`. Also, you may want to pass your constructor parameter `f` as a const reference, not just const.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Same for second constructor parameter.

Comment: @TimStraubinger Const reference parameter wouldn't allow to move from an rvalue argument. Better to use non-const pass-by-value mechanism and then move from parameter to member variable, as @WhiZTim suggested. (Or, to use forwarding reference and `std::forward`. Or, to use two variants of constructor for lvalue and rvalue arguments...)

Comment: Ok, thank you! It was the destructor definition. I will also incorporate the other suggestions.